# Does a 64-bit CruiseControl.NET exist?

Tags: iis-6, 64-bit, cruisecontrol.net, windows-server-2003

Does a 64-bit CruiseControl.NET exist or do I need to install the 32-bit version? Our CI server is Server2003 64-bit. Currently I have been testing on WinXP Pro and no problems.

If I do need to run cc.net 32-bit on a 64-bit OS, what issues should I expect to encounter? This post mentions a couple, [Running 32-bit ASP.NEt 3.5 apps in Windows 2003 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701997/running-32-bit-asp-net-3-5-apps-in-windows-2003-64-bit) . I would also need to have the .NET 2.0 and 3.5 framework installed. Do I install the 32-bit versions if running cc.net 32-bit? Can 32-bit and 64-bit coexist on the same server?

Comment: Please find another SO thread discussed about same issue. I hope that will solve your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335812/cruisecontrol-net-on-windows-server-2003-x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick peek at the source code reveals that CruiseControl.NET is compiled with "Any CPU" platform, so it will (and does) run on either a 32 or 64 bit runtime.

My notebook runs 64 bit O/S and has no problems with CruiseControl.NET server or web dashboard (IIS 7).  Just install it as per normal and you should be fine.

Personally I'd be really worried if it needed > 3GB of memory :)

Comment: That's the point. "Any CPU" means "Let the runtime engine take care of it". CPU specific compilation is relevant if you have unmanaged code. As far as I know CCNET is managed code only.

Comment: Of course you specify x86 or x64 in the build process, or run ngen after installation.  What's also interesting is that apparently in VS 2010, "Any CPU" platform won't be the default: http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/08/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be anything you need to worry about.  Cruise control just launches the build, subsequent steps such as compilation can be 64-bit.

Comment: I didn't mean what cc.net does as a build process. I meant actually installing cc.net. So to install cc.net on server2003 64-bit, I need to install cc.net via WOW64 then?

Comment: if by "install cc.net via WOW64" you mean install it normally and have windows take care of the WOW64 part, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's much benefit from making CruiseControl 64-bit at the moment. I'm running CruiseControl without issues on a 64-bit machine. The setup was not much different, other than the folder which it was installed into (Program files (x86)).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, all 32bit applications will work on a 64bit OS.  I have been doing this with my webapps for some time.  You will encounter issues only if you are trying to reference assemblies across the bit boundary, ie. 64bit assembly from 32bit application.

You should be already to run CC on 32bit mode on 64bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

There are no seperate version of CruiseControl for 64-bit. But but you may run into an ASP.NET error if working with Win. Server 2008 and IIS7.

Workaround:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe" -i
```

and

```
 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe" -i "W3SVC/1/ROOT/ccnet"
```

NOTE: it is using Framework64 as this would not work for 32-bit.